# Finding an irrational function with horizontal asymptotes y=1 and y=5

Tags: analysis, functions

I can't seem to find an irrational function with $2$ horizontal asymptotes $y=1$ and $y=5$.

I've looked everywhere and tried all I know, I keep getting $2$ asymptotes that the contrary of each other eg. $y=1$ and $y=-1$.

(The function can't be a composition of 2 functions and it HAS to be an irrational function)

I'd appreciate any help!
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:
I THINK THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER

$$
f(x)=\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}+3
$$

Comment: Let $f$ be a rational function with asymptotes $y=1, y=-1$. Then look at the function $2f+3$

Comment: A rational function has at most one horizontal asymptote.

Comment: An example of an irrational function with 2 non-contrary horizontal assymptotes would help me a lot!

Comment: Try $\arctan$, then scale it and shift it up.

Comment: What is an irrational function, please?

Comment: A function where the root of the unkown value is taken eg. sqrt(x+1)

Comment: regarding the "EDIT" at the end: you think *what* is the correct answer?

Comment: The "Correct answer" is not defined at $0,$ and is otherwise constant for positive x, and constant for negative x. (the two constants are the two desired asymptotes, but the example doesn't seem as good as one defined on all reals.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Two strictly increasing functions taking values in $(-1, 1)$ are
$$
f(x) = \tanh x = \frac{e^{x} - e^{-x}}{e^{x} + e^{-x}},\qquad
g(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^{2}}}.
$$
If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, consider a function of the form $h(x) = a + bf(x)$ or $a + bg(x)$.

Comment: I think $g(x)$ of this answers the question, with "irrational function" defined as the OP has seemingly done in comments. +1.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most ''similar'' to a rational function that i can find:

$$
y=\dfrac{2x^2+3|x|x+|x|}{x|x|}
$$
If you consider irrational a function where $x$ is under a root, than subsitute $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ and the function is ''irrational''.

Comment: It has to be an irrational function.

Comment: Sorry!!! You can sobstitute $|x| =\sqrt(x^2)$ :)

Comment: Yeah the function $$f(x)=\frac{2x^2+3\sqrt{x^2}\cdot \:x+\sqrt{x^2}}{x\cdot \sqrt{x^2}}$$ is correct thanks.

Comment: Note that this function has ''proper'' asymptotes. The function in OP has ''values'' $1, 5$

Comment: Well both have assymptotes y = 1 and y = 5 so both are correct by definition although I have to agree yours looks better in a graph lol.

Comment: $$f(x)=\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}+3$$ I adjusted the function a bit and this one has 'proper' asymptotes.